# Praat scripts throw "unknown function" errors in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, praat

I wrote the simplest praat script, and it runs fine on my Mac:

```
Read from file... sound.wav
selectObject (1)
```

It assumes there's a wave file called sound.wav. However, when I try to do the same on my Ubuntu Linux box, I get the error:

```
Error: Unknown function «selectObject» in formula.
Script line 2 not performed or completed:
« selectObject (1) »
```

I tried with selectObject(1), selectObject(0) and other variations, and they all fail. However, if I do "plus Sound sound" it seems to work. Right after that, if I try to do

```
s = do ("To Manipulation...", 0.01, 75, 600)
```

that works on my Mac too, but also fails on Ubuntu with

```
Error: Unknown function «do» in formula.
```

Why is that? How can I make it work?

I installed praat on Ubuntu using sudo apt-get install praat. Tried it with Ubuntu 12 and 13, and it fails in both cases.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer to my own question: getting the praat binaries from the praat site works. The ones from aptitude do not.

Comment: Versions in the repositories are never the latest versions. In your simplest of scripts you were using `selectObject()` and `do()`, both of which are recent additions to the language. When I wrote this the version in the repositories was still 5.3.16, and these changes didn't happen until 5.3.44. When the version in the repos gets updated then those binaries should work fine as well.

Comment: This post saved me from a headache ...